Getting conserved current from electromagnetic field-strength tensor
The equation of motion that we get from the electromagnetic lagrangian is:
$$ \partial _\mu ( F ^{\mu \nu}) + J ^\nu = 0 \tag{A} $$
Here $J$ is the conserved current that couples to the field $A_\mu$.
Conserverly, using this equation of motion, we can also find the current J that is creating the tensor $F ^{\mu \nu}$. Let's take for example the field-strength tensor due to a static point electric charge $q$ located at origin. It will only generate electric field $ \vec{E} = \frac{q}{4 \pi} \frac{\vec{r}}{|r|^3}$ and no magnetic field. So the field strength tensor will be:
$$ F _{\mu \nu}(x) = \pmatrix{ 0 & \frac{-qx}{4 \pi r^3} & \frac{-qy}{4 \pi r^3} & \frac{-qz}{4 \pi r^3} \\\\ \frac{qx}{4 \pi r^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\ \frac{qy}{4 \pi r^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\\ \frac{qz}{4 \pi r^3} & 0 & 0 & 0 } 
 \tag{B}$$
However, I expect the current to be ( because it is located at origin and moving only in time ):
$$ J^\mu = \pmatrix{ q \delta(\vec{x}) \\\\0\\\\0\\\\0 } \tag{C}$$
To test my understanding, we will plug this $F_{\mu\nu}$ ( after raising indices appropriately ) with $\nu$ fixed to 0. This gives:
$$ \partial_x \left( \frac{qx}{4\pi r^3} \right) + \partial_y \left( \frac{qy}{4\pi r^3} \right) +  \partial_z \left( \frac{qz}{4\pi r^3} \right)  +  J^0 = 0 $$
$$ \frac{1}{ (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} - 3 \frac{x^2}{ (x^2 + y ^2 + z^2)^{5/2}} +  \frac{1}{ (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} - 3 \frac{y^2}{ (x^2 + y ^2 + z^2)^{5/2}} +  \frac{1}{ (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}} - 3 \frac{z^2}{ (x^2 + y ^2 + z^2)^{5/2}}  = \frac{-4 \pi J^0}{q} $$
$$ \frac{3}{r^3} - \frac{3 r^2}{r^5} = \frac{-4 \pi J^0}{q} \tag{D}$$
Now it seems like the LHS is becoming zero for finite r, as expected. But my question is : where is the delta function?
I can see that there are some subtleties at $ r \rightarrow 0 $ in the LHS. So maybe it is equivalent to a delta function somehow. I am not sure. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to get $J^0$ component to be a delta function which was anticipated in equation (C) ?

Your problem boils down to proving the formula $$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \frac{\vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|^3} = 4 \pi \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}) \tag{1} \label{1}$$ in the framework of the theory of distributions. Eq. \eqref{1} means that $$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3}\! d^3x \, \phi(\vec{x})  \vec{\nabla} \cdot\frac{\vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|^3}:=-\!\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} \! d^3x \, \vec{\nabla}\phi(\vec{x}) \cdot \frac{\vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|^3}=-\lim\limits_{\epsilon \downarrow 0}\!\!\int \limits_{|\vec{x}|\ge \epsilon}\! d^3x \, \vec{\nabla} \phi(\vec{x}) \cdot \frac{\vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|^3}=4\pi \phi(\vec{0}) \tag{2} \label{2}$$ holds for arbitrary test functions $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)$. As $\phi$ has compact support, there exists $a \gt 0$ such that $\phi(\vec{x})$ (together with all its derivatives) vanishes for $|\vec{x}|\ge a$. Therefore, $$I:=-\!\!\int\limits_{|\vec{x}|\ge \epsilon \gt 0} \! d^3x \, \vec{\nabla} \phi(\vec{x}) \cdot \frac{\vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|^3}=-\int\limits_V\! d^3x \, \vec{\nabla} \phi(\vec{x}) \cdot \frac{\vec{x}}{|\vec{x}|^3} \tag{3} \label{3}$$ with $V= \{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3| \epsilon \le |\vec{x}|\le a\}$. As $\vec{0} \notin V$, we can write $$I=\int\limits_V \! d^3x \, \vec{\nabla}\phi(\vec{x}) \cdot \vec{\nabla} \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|}=\int\limits_V \! d^3x \,\left\{ \nabla_i\left[\phi(\vec{x}) \nabla_i\frac{1}{|\vec{x}|}  \right]-\phi(\vec{x}) \Delta \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|}\right\}, \tag{4} \label{4}$$ where summation convention was used. Noting that $\Delta( 1/|\vec{x}|)=0$ for $\vec{x} \ne \vec{0}$ and employing the integral theorem of Gauss, we find $$I= \int\limits_{ \partial V} \! d\sigma_i \, \phi(\vec{x}) \nabla_i \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|} \tag{5} \label{5}.$$ The contribution from the part of the boundary $\partial V$ with $|\vec{x}|=a$ vanishes because of $\phi(\vec{x})=0$ for $|\vec{x}|=a$ and we are left with $$I=- \epsilon^2 \int\limits_{S^2}\! d\Omega \frac{x_i}{|\vec{x}|} \phi(\vec{x})\nabla_i \frac{1}{|\vec{x}|} {\huge|}_{|\vec{x}|=\epsilon}=- \epsilon^2\int\limits_{S^2} \! d\Omega \,\phi(\vec{x})  \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\frac{1}{r}}_{-1/r^2} {\huge|}_{r=\epsilon} \to  4\pi \phi(\vec{0}) \quad \text{for} \; \epsilon \downarrow 0, \tag{6}$$ verifying indeed \eqref{2}.
